# Where are the pregenerated character sheets for the Hunt for the Thessalhydra adventure on D&D Beyond?

Tags: dnd-5e, published-adventures, dnd-beyond, pregenerated-characters

I've just bought the [Hunt for the Thessalhydra](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/hftt/hunt-for-the-thessalhydra) adventure (from the [Stranger Things Starter Set](https://dnd.wizards.com/products/tabletop-games/rpg-products/stranger-things-dd-roleplaying-game-starter-set)) on D&D Beyond, but the pregenerated character sheets from the boxed set aren't visible.

Where can I find these on D&D Beyond or otherwise?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are not available, from the [DnD Beyond Forum](https://www.dndbeyond.com/forums/d-d-beyond-general/d-d-beyond-feedback/40919-hunt-for-the-thessalhydra-pre-gens), as per 15 June 2019:

> DDB currently doesn't have a means to copy character sheets from one user to another. Without this framework, they have no way of providing access to pre-gens; it's the same for the starter kit.
>
> Intra-user copying is coming, and with it will come access to pregen characters.